# Unable to show comma separated values in a table

Tags: php, html, mysql

I have `id`'s stored as comma separated values in my database table and I want to show listing of each `id`'s respective name in a html table. Till now I have failed to find some solution for this because whats happening currently is the table is showing `values` only for the first id picked up in the comma separated listing. Can I have some insights on this to how to show up each id's value as comma separated in html table.

```
<table id="example"   class="table table-striped table-hover table-bordered  dt-responsive nowrap"  cellspacing="0" width="100%">
<thead>
<tr>

<th>S No.</th>
<th>Level :<br>(Attempt)</th>
<th>Candidate's<br>Designation->id</th>
<th>Reporting<br>Head->id</th>
<th>mail To :</th>
<th>mail CC :</th>
<th>Status</th>
</tr>
</thead>
<tbody>
    <?php

     $sqlQuerybatch     =   "SELECT * from tbl WHERE status = 1 ";

     $sq1           =   $db->query($sqlQuerybatch);
     $i             =   1 ;
    if($db->affected_rows > 0)
    {
        while($row=mysql_fetch_array($sq1))
        {
         extract($row);
         $des_cc=explode(',', $designation_cc_email);

       foreach($des_cc as $out) {
          $out = $rep; 
       }

     $sql_designation =  "SELECT designation from tbl_designation WHERE id = $designation_id ";
                  $sqdes            =   $db->query($sql_designation);
                 if($db->affected_rows > 0)
    {
        while($rowdes=mysql_fetch_array($sqdes))
        { 
        $desid =  $rowdes['designation'];
        } 

             $sql_designation1 =  "SELECT designation from tbl_designation WHERE id = $designation_email ";
                  $sqdes1           =   $db->query($sql_designation1);
                 if($db->affected_rows > 0)
    {
        while($rowdes1=mysql_fetch_array($sqdes1))
        { 
        $desid1 =  $rowdes1['designation'];
        } 

                 $sql_reporting =  "SELECT designation_id,reporting_head from tbl_reporting_head WHERE reporting_head_for = $designation_id and status=1";
                  $sqdes2           =   $db->query($sql_reporting);
                 if($db->affected_rows > 0)
    {
        while($rowdes2=mysql_fetch_array($sqdes2))
        { 
        $desid2 =  $rowdes2['reporting_head'];
        $reportingheadid = $rowdes2['designation_id'];
        } 

      $sql_reporting1 =  "SELECT designation from tbl_designation WHERE id in($rep) ";
        $sqdes3             =   $db->query($sql_reporting1);
      if($db->affected_rows > 0)
    {   
        while($rowdes3=mysql_fetch_array($sqdes3))
        { 
        $desid3 =  $rowdes3['designation'];
        }    
     ?>               
 <tr>
<td><?php echo $i ; ?></td>
<td><?php echo $attemp ; ?></td>
<td><?php echo $desid." -> ".$designation_id ; ?></td>
<td><?php echo $desid2." -> ".$reportingheadid ; ?></td>
<td><?php echo $desid1 ; ?></td> 
<td><?php echo $status ; ?></td>
</tr>
<?php $i++;}} }}}}?>                

</tbody>
</table>
```

`$desid3` is where I want to show values like `A,B` and so on.
What I am getting here is only A in each html table row. Sorry for the messed up code but have been trying so many things but not getting the exact result.

Comment: You are overwriting the variable(s) you are using in many of your loops.  Basically you will be left with the last value in the array.  Which is why you only get one value from your variables that are assigned in the loops.

Answer (score 0):

All your loops are wrong,  For example

```
foreach($des_cc as $out) {
   $out = $rep; 
}
```

The problem here is you are overwriting the variable on each iteration without using is.  What this does is you end up with only the last value being in the variable.  Also in this case your assignment is backwards too.  You should have:

```
foreach($des_cc as $out) {
   $rep = $out; 
}
```

Unless your trying to do something totally different, but regardless it's wrong.  For example you could be trying to update the value, but even that it's not done right.

Anyway.

What you have to do is inside the loop, you need to put the HTML you are outputting so you can output the value on each iteration of the loop.

So just for examples sake, lets say `$des_cc` is an array like this:

```
$des_cc = [1,2,3,4,5,6];
```

Now well take your loop

```
foreach($des_cc as $out) {
   $rep = $out; 
}

echo $rep;
```

This will output

```
6
```

Which is the last value assigned to `$rep`.  Now had we output that variable inside the loop like this:

```
foreach($des_cc as $out) {
   $rep = $out; 
   echo $rep;
}
```

It would output this (assuming we added a line return):

```
1
2
3
4
5
6
```

The same holds true if you put that variable into your HTML.  Hope that makes sense.

A few other examples of this mistake in your code:

```
while($rowdes=mysql_fetch_array($sqdes)){ 
    $desid =  $rowdes['designation'];
}
```

AND

```
while($rowdes2=mysql_fetch_array($sqdes2))
{ 
    $desid2 =  $rowdes2['reporting_head'];
    $reportingheadid = $rowdes2['designation_id'];
}
```

The other thing you can do, is store that data into another array, like this

```
 $rep = []
 foreach($des_cc as $out) {
    $rep[] = $out; 
 }
```

This example basically copies the array into `$rep` one element at a time.  I don't think that is what you want, I only mention it for completeness.

Comment: Thanks for the advice. I really appreciate your insights. I am still a beginner and will start looking into these points and lot more to learn. But can I know how to make this piece of code work. I mean can you send me the edited code which I posted.

Comment: No, there is to much wrong with it.  There are to many queries, to many fragments.  So it's not entirely clear what the end result would be and likly I would have to have the Database setup etc.  Otherwise I'm flying blind.  It just to much of a time sink.  Sorry but I would probably have to rewrite the whole thing.  And you wouldn't learn anything that way.

Comment: :)  Ok thnaks for the time.

Comment: Sure, as I said if I rewrote it you wouldn't learn anything from it and you would find yourself back in the same situation sooner rather then later.  And that is before considering the setup time it would take me to replicate your database etc.  Good luck.  The best advice I can say is build it slowly piece by piece.  For example layout a table with some hard coded data in just HTML, then add some PHP in it and build up the complexity.  That will make each piece a bit easier to handle.

Comment: Also be lazy, if you find yourself doing multiple queries to the same table see if you can combine them.  Sometimes a bit more complex query can save a ton of coding when you go to render it.

Comment: One other thing I see is a lot of variable confusion (that is what I call it).  An example is this `SELECT designation from tbl_designation` then you assign it to `$desid =  $rowdes['designation'];`.  But just a bit later you have `SELECT designation_id,reporting_head from tbl_reporting_head` and you assign that to `$desid2 =  $rowdes2['reporting_head']` and `$reportingheadid = $rowdes2['designation_id'];`    So you have `$desid`, `$desid1` from one table, and `$desid2` from another with the wrong field?

Comment: Basically it can be very confusing when a variable is named `$desid{n}` and it comes from different sources.  Don't be afraid to be verbose with variable names (use more descriptive names).  Also try to avoid using instance variables, where you only use it one time and right after you declare it.   An example of this is, `$sqlQuerybatch     =   "SELECT * ...";` then you use it 1 time `$db->query($sqlQuerybatch);`, instead you can just do `$db->query("SELECT * ...");`  And avoid assigning so many variables.

Comment: Thanks again for being so descriptive and sparing your valuable time for me. I really appreciate. I would just like to ask one clarification from you. I have `3,5` stored in the db, I just want to separate these two,find their respective names from another table,and then show names on the second last column in html table as comma separated name. How can this be achievable. Just some insight on this.

Comment: @ArtisticPhoenix they're mixing different mysql apis here. Notice the `$db->query`? That suggests mysqli_ since mysql_ does not offer an object oriented method. Unless they're using a custom method, but I doubt that. I only saw this answer from them reposting basically the same question today.  `$db->affected_rows` also suggests mysqli_, since the link identifier is first here and mysql_'s link method goes second. Edit: we don't even know if they connected, and if so; how? *heh*

Comment: @FunkFortyNiner - nice catch, thanks for pointing that out!  Personally I don't like mysqli, it's more confusing then PDO.  It always seemed like a half measure to me..