# how to show all values in a single <td>

Tags: php, mysql, html-table

I want to show my values based on `id` in a single `<td>` for each iteration separated by comma(,). How this can be implement? Currently using my code I am getting `<td>`'s based on number of iterations, i.e. if I have 3 `id`'s then my code makes 3 `<td>`s. Any insight will be helpful. 
 My code,

```
<?php
$des_cc = explode(',', $designation_cc_email);
$repo = array();

foreach($des_cc as $out)
{
    $repo[] = $out;
    $sql_reporting1 = "SELECT designation from tbl WHERE id = $out ";
    $sqdes3 = $db->query($sql_reporting1);
    while ($rowdes3 = mysql_fetch_array($sqdes3))
    {
        $desid3 = $rowdes3['designation'];
    }

    echo "<td>" . $desid3 . "</td>";
}

?>
```

Comment: How do you want the IDs displayed in the `td`?

Comment: Thanks for the prompt response. Currently if I get three designations from tbl  then my code is making three different <td>. I want to show all thre in one <td> separated by comma.

Comment: `$db->query` this suggests mysqli_ since mysql_ does not offer an object oriented method and you're using a mysql_ function after that. What is the connection, mysql_ or mysqli_?

Comment: This is also a repost of [your earlier question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/49585558/unable-to-show-comma-separated-values-in-a-table) where you were mixing different mysql apis; you can't do that. I closed the question.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Ofcourse, you are in a loop, that's why you are getting 3 `<td>`s.

Try the follow, taking HTML code out of the loop

```
<?php   
$des_cc=explode(',', $designation_cc_email);
$repo=array();
$desid3 = [];
foreach($des_cc as $out) {
  $repo[]= $out;
  $sql_reporting1 =  "SELECT designation from tbl WHERE id = $out ";
  $sqdes3 = $db->query($sql_reporting1);

  while($rowdes3=mysql_fetch_array($sqdes3))
  { 
    $desid3[] = $rowdes3['designation'];
  }
}
echo "<td>".implode(' ', $desid3)."</td>";   
?>
```

Inside `implode()`, use any separator of your choice. Or you can manually generate some string to be placed in `<td>` as `$desid3` will be an `array`

Answer (score 1):

If I am not wrong, you wish to display comma separated designations in the **td**. If yes, then do this:

```
$desigs = array();
while ($rowdes3 = mysql_fetch_array($sqdes3))
{
    $desigs[] = $rowdes3['designation'];
}

echo "<td>" . implode(",",$desigs) . "</td>";
```

Comment: Tried this but still the same result.

Answer (score -1):

Try this

```
<td>
    <?php
     while($rowdes3=mysql_fetch_array($sqdes3))
        { 
           $desid3 =  $rowdes3['designation'];
           echo $desid3.","; 
         }    
          ?> 
    </td>
```

Write `<td>` outside your while loop

Comment: This code has syntax errors.

Comment: `echo $desid3.","; ` that will still leave them with a trailing comma.